# Why use GAN in NLG?

Tags: nlp, gan, text-generation

I am interested in the GAN recently. There are many papers that recently applied GAN to NLG.

I do not know much about NLP or NLG, but I wonder why I use GAN for NLG. For better quality? Or for many variations?

Comment: In what other fields have you used GANs for?

Comment: NLG for "Natural Language Generation"? Can you provide pointers to the many papers that recently applied GANs to  NLG?